# Why can't I search mails older than 1 year in Outlook?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-server-2012, microsoft-outlook-2013, exchange-2013

We have our mailboxes running on Exchange 2013.

We also have Outlook 2013 running in online mode (no cache files / ost and pst)

When our users use the search function, mails older than 1 year are not being shown. There is no button under those mails that says "show older mails".

Does anyone know why we are unable to search mails older than 1 year?

Indexing on the mailbox database is working without issues.

Answer (score 0):

can you confirm you're not archiving mails older than 1 year?
Do you use PSTs?
Are you using some GPO settings to manage Outlook or Windows Search?
Which is the OS?

Comment: This should not be an answer, but a comment to the question for clearifing.

Comment: Sorry for my late response. We are not archiving mails older than 1 year. We do not use PSTs. No GPO's are in place to manage Windows Search. Our mail server is running Server 2012 R2 and our users are on terminal servers running 2012 R2